# How to write a file after a given run time with MPI?

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

I have a simulation code written in C, parallel with MPI, running on a linux Cluster that kills jobs after 12h of wall time. Jobs that last longer than 12h must then be restarted from a file written by the program.

My code currently write these 'restart files' every N steps of my simulation. It is important that each node is at the same simulation step before writing the restart file.

In my case, these files are big (> 1GB/process) therefore I cannot write the as often as I would need (takes to much time and space).

Also, the execution time of one simulation step depends on what is going on within the simulation, as a result it is quite difficult to predict on many steps my simulation will have done within the 12h. So I cannot either decide to write the restart file after the number of step I think will be done just before the 12h of run time.

As a result, when my job is killed, the last restart file may have been written several hours before, which then forces me do redo a substantial part of the last 12h execution.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to write a restart file as a function of the elapsed run time. I have thought of using MPI_Wtime(), however for a given runtime, say 11:50:00, all processors won't necessarily be at the same phase step... which is not good. Is there a simple solution to that problem ?

Comment: I think the question is too vague, as it stands, to be answered properly. Can you give more details about the structure of the code?

Comment: Some MPI implementations support checkpointing. For example, Open MPI can be compiled with [BLCR](https://ftg.lbl.gov/projects/CheckpointRestart/). Most workload managers can be instructed to deliver a signal some time before the job runs near the end of its requested run-time and a signal handler might call into the BLCR checkpointing.

Answer (score 3):

Once your processes hit the 11:50:00 mark (or some other suitable deadline), have them AllReduce the number of iterations completed using `MPI_MAX`. Then they can catch up to exactly that number of iterations, and wait for everyone else to do the same with a simple Barrier. They can then start writing the restart file.

Comment: The problem I see is that you cannot ensure that in the remaining time (say 10 minutes) all the processes will have enough time to catch up that number of iterations.

Comment: In general you're right Genis. What I didn't say, and might be important, is that every time step im my simulation involves global communications so processors are still synced at some point during at each time step.

They might however not be synced at the location where I want to write the restart file.

Comment: Basically, the structure of the code is the following : 

TimeLoop iter=0..end
    SomeSolving() // this involve global comm
    if(iter%N ==0) write_restart_file()
EndTimeLoop

And I'd like to replace the if(iter%N==0) by a checking of the elapsed time. BEcause the SomeSolving() routine involves global comm. I'm sure that some processors won't be more than 1 step ahead the others I guess.

However I cannot simply replace the if(iter%N==0) by if(elapsedTime>11:50:00) because that wouldn't be true for all processes at the same iter.

Comment: Here is a code that I think mimics what I said : http://pastebin.com/0hDhYK9g
Do you agree ?